# Sed: can not replace part of the string whithout replacing all of it

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am trying to replace part of the string, but can not find a proper regex for sed to execute it properly.

I have a string
`/abc/foo/../bar`
And I would like to achive the following result:
`/abc/bar`

I have tried to do it using this command:

`echo $string | sed 's/\/[^:-]*\..\//\//'`

But as result I am getting just `/bar`.

I understand that I must use group, but I just do not get it.
Could you, please, help me to find out this group that could be used?

Comment: Why is your bracket expression `[^:-]` when your string contains neither `:` nor `-`? Why is your regexp testing for `\.` when your string doesn't contain any `.`s? Are you maybe showing us sample input that isn't truly representative of your real input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
#!/bin/bash
string='/abc/foo/../bar'
sed -nE 's~^(/[^/]*)(/.*)?/\.\.(/[^/]*).*~\1\3~p' <<< "$string"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/YawsuO). *Details*:

- `-n` - suppresses default line output
- `E` - enables POSIX ERE regex syntax
- `^` - start of string
- `(/[^/]*)` - Group 1: a `/` and then zero or more chars other than `/`
- `(/.*)?` - an optional group 2: a `/` and then any text
- `/\.\.` - a `/..` fixed string
- `(/[^/]*)` - Group 3: a `/` and then zero or more chars other than `/`
- `.*` - the rest of the string.
- `\1\3` replaces the match with Group 1 and 3 values concatenated
- `p`  only prints the result of successful substitution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capture group for the first part and then match until the last `/` to remove.

As you are using `/` to match in the pattern, you can opt for a different delimiter.

```
#!/bin/bash
string="/abc/foo/../bar"

sed 's~\(/[^/]*/\)[^:-]*/~\1~' <<< "$string"
```

The pattern in parts:

- `\(` Capture **group 1**

  - `/[^/]*/` Match from the first till the second `/` with any char other than `/` in between
- `\)`  Close group 1
- `[^:-]*/` Match optional chars other than `:` and `-` then match `/`

Output

```
/abc/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
$ sed 's#^\(/[^/]*\)/.*\(/\)#\1\2#' input_file
/abc/bar
```

or

```
$ sed 's#[^/]*/[^/]*/##2' input_file
/abc/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
string='/abc/foo/../bar'
awk -F/ '{print "/"$2"/"$NF}' <<< "$string"
#or
awk -F/ 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{print $1,$2,$NF}' <<< "$string"
```

---

```
/abc/bar
```

Using bash

```
string='/abc/foo/../bar'
echo "${string%%/${string#*/*/}}/${string##*/}"
```

---

```
/abc/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any sed:

```
$ echo "$string" | sed 's:\(/[^/]*/\).*/:\1:'
/abc/bar
```